# Visualize a set of arrays using matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I want to visualize a set of arrays overtime (with some pause in between) using matplotlib. What I have so far is the visualization for one array but I don't know how to make it like an animation. This is the code I have so far which creates a list of arrays and successfully visualizes the first array in the list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
plt.style.use('classic')

a = []
for i in xrange(5):
    temp = np.zeros((5,5))
    temp[i, i] = 10
    a.append(temp)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, 5, figsize=(5, 5))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace=0)

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        ax[i, j].xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
        ax[i, j].yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
        if a[0][i,j] == 10:
            ax[i, j].imshow(Image.open('A.png'), cmap="bone")
        else:
            ax[i, j].imshow(Image.open('B.png'), cmap="bone")

plt.show()
```

How can I visualize all arrays of the list like an animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to import the animation module and define a function that changes the frame to show each image you captured.

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

    def update(i):
        label = 'timestep {0}'.format(i)
        //Insert the data the frame here Eg:ax.imgshow(Image.open('A.png'), cmap="bone")
        ax.set_xlabel(label)
        return line, ax

    FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(0, 10), interval=200)

    plt.show()
```

You can follow this handy guide:

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/drawing-animated-gifs-with-matplotlib/